# cannot find module error in node js when there is a file in a folder which is in a folder

Tags: javascript, node.js, server, module

[server.js inside of 01 folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oHYAE.jpg)I have a server.js file inside of a folder called 01, which is in the node-js file of my project. When I try to run 'node server' in the terminal I get the below error. It states that it cannot find the module. It seems as if vs code does not recognise the 01 folder.

I have tried to run 'node server' in the terminal and was expecting to get the 'hi' from the console.log statement to appear. I have tried to re download vs code, update everything, search all over the internet.
[server.js file outside of 01 folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GHM4t.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to move the server.js to root folder and run.

Can you also post your package.json scripts and the folder structure screenshot ?